# Converting Data Provider for Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to migrate an Entity Framework Model from SQL server to MySql.

I'm doing this because I'd like to do a project with Entity Framework to learn more about it, but I am on a shared server that only allows 1 SQL server database (which I'm using),  and 5 mysql databases. It's possible that I'd move servers in the future, so I like the idea of database independence.

I'm having trouble actually doing my first conversion experiment. I have created a EDMX Model in Visual studio 2010, and  schema and used the 'Generate database from model' to get my SQL Server schema.

Now, I thought that I would be able to do a simple 'Change Data Source' and change my datasource to mysql then 'Generate database from model' again to get my new MySQL schema, but no such luck.

I downloaded  MySQL Connector/NET 6.0.5 and (when that didn't work) 6.1.3, but MySql just does not appear in my list of possible data providers.

I also noticed that I can't make a connection to MySQL in the server explorer in Visual studio 2010, like I can in VS2008.

> -Has anyone done this?
>   -Is it even possible to change data providers in the way that I am thinking?
>   -Does anyone have a tutorial that can help me?

Comment: Here is a screenshot:
(http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/12/36315355065-orig.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Connector/NET does not support EF v4 Beta 2. 
Neither does Devart dotConnect for MySQL, our implementation is still in progress. 
Devart Team 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect 
ADO.NET data providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite with
Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL support

Comment: Devart dotConnect version 5.70 and higher now supports EF v4. Version 5.70 is available since April 2010.